# Drivers for gaming Nvidia and wine and what happened to wine tricks?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, wine, games, winetricks

Which Nvidia driver should I be using for gaming under wine?

I ask this question after installing one of my favourite games ,sins of a solar empire, in wine. The game seems to run fine, it's not too graphics intensive and my GPU is good and quick, but the problem I found was I could not change the resolution and it only listed random refresh rates like 42hz and 57hz and then after a restart I could not start the game without Unity been displayed as well so I figure it could be drivers.

Is there a preferred driver (Im using 310 tested) also is the driver from the nvidia site better?

And finally where did wine tricks go? I can't find it in the repository any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones at the nvidia website are probably newer, but I don't think you'd notice the difference, and from my experience, you should stick with the proprietary drivers in the repositories, as they are easier to install/update/remove and you're less likely to have any problems. The problem's you're describing are most likely related to Wine than with the GPU drivers. Do check the [WineHQ entry](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6653) and try it with [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/).

Comment: Thanks for the response I will keep the 310 stable driver then and check out play on linux